# MSDTC over network does not work in Azure Pipeline Microsoft hosted agents

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, distributed-transactions

I have the following scenario. I am running a pipeline in Microsoft Hosted agent windows-2022. In the pipeline process, I run a sql server container, which serves as my database server. My application is present in the agent itself. It communicates with the containerized database server.

I have setup the DTC networking in both the agent as well as in the container by running the following powershell:

```
Set-DtcNetworkSetting -DtcName 'Local' -AuthenticationLevel 'NoAuth' -InboundTransactionsEnabled $true -OutboundTransactionsEnabled $true -RemoteClientAccessEnabled $true -RemoteAdministrationAccessEnabled $true -XATransactionsEnabled $true -Confirm:$false
```

Additionally, in the agent I have run the following powershell to allow DTC over firewall:

```
Enable-NetFirewallRule -DisplayGroup "Distributed Transaction Coordinator"
```

Whenever a pipelines runs on Microsoft Hosted windows agents, it shows up 2 different types of agent names:

1. Starts with 'WIN-'. Ex: WIN-IIS1P4PRUUV
2. Starts with 'fv-az'. Ex: fv-az378-745

The observation here is whenever the pipeline runs on the 'WIN-' agent, it runs perfectly fine without any MSDTC error. But the exact same setup does not work whenever it runs on 'fv-az' agent. Even with all the settings, it gives the following error:

```
The MSDTC transaction manager was unable to pull the transaction from the source transaction manager due to communication problems. Possible causes are: a firewall is present and it doesn't have an exception for the MSDTC process, the two machines cannot find each other by their NetBIOS names, or the support for network transactions is not enabled for one of the two transaction managers.
```

If I do the exact setup in an windows-2022 VM, it runs perfectly fine.

My question is, why there is a different behavior in 'WIN-' and 'fv-az' agents? What is the difference between these 2 groups and why with all the settings MSDTC works fine in one agent and not on other?

Answer (score 0):

The agent machines whose names begin with `win-` are the nested VMs while `fv-` machines are non-nested VMs. Accordingly to your description, the issue seemed to only occur on non-nested VMs. And there could be reduced job performance and environment differences.

As a workaround for now, you may considering [Setting up Windows self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops) for stable pipeline jobs.

Comment: So why there is a different behavior and can I expect a fix from Microsoft for this? Using self-hosted agent is not recommended in my company unless the resources are in internal network.